# Getting chart via javascript and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, charts

I try to push data from database (data_viewer) to javascript chart but doesnt work. I need to display data_viewer as y: ... (in label: "Vada 1", y: data_viewer). Anybody knows what I´m doing wrong? Thank you.
Database connection is ok and the graph seems to be ok also. But no data from database.

```
    <?php
    require('db_config.php');

    /* Getting srot_data vada */
    $sql = "SELECT count(blok) AS count FROM srot_data WHERE Vada = '1' GROUP BY vada";
    $viewer = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    $viewer = mysqli_fetch_all($viewer,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $viewer = json_encode(array_column($viewer, 'count'),JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

?>
    <script>

window.onload = function () {  

var data_viewer = <?php echo $viewer; ?>;
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    title:{
        text: "PPM 1"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Hodnoty",
        lineColor: "#4F81BC",
        tickColor: "#4F81BC",
        labelFontColor: "#4F81BC"
    },
    axisY2: {
        title: "Procenta",
        suffix: "%",
        lineColor: "#C0504E",
        tickColor: "#C0504E",
        labelFontColor: "#C0504E"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
      { label: "Vada 1", y: data_viewer },
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();
createPareto(); 

function createPareto(){
    var dps = [];
    var yValue, yTotal = 0, yPercent = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < chart.data[0].dataPoints.length; i++)
        yTotal += chart.data[0].dataPoints[i].data_viewer;

    for(var i = 0; i < chart.data[0].dataPoints.length; i++){
        yValue = chart.data[0].dataPoints[i].data_viewer;
        yPercent += (yValue / yTotal * 100);
        dps.push({label: chart.data[0].dataPoints[i].data_viewer, y: yPercent});
    }

    chart.addTo("data",{type:"line", yValueFormatString: "0.##\"%\"", dataPoints: dps});
    chart.data[1].set("axisYType", "secondary", false);
    chart.axisY[0].set("maximum", yTotal);
    chart.axisY2[0].set("maximum", 100);
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: Debug :-)  Look at your `$viewer` variable, does it contain what you expect from your query?   Add `print $viewer;` at every step and confirm that the values are good.  I expect not looking at that code...   `mysqli_query` returns a mysqli_result object.  `mysqli_result ` returns an array.  `mysqli_result ` returns a string.  So why use the same `$viewer` variable over and over?  Confusing and bound for errors.

Comment: you are right :) thank you :)